# Verify that the given vector satisfies the given differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\vec x' = \begin{bmatrix}3 & -2 \\ 2 & -2\end{bmatrix} \vec x; \qquad \vec x = \begin{bmatrix}2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix} e^{2t}.$$
So I was wondering how can I verify the vector satisfies the differential equation? Any tips/solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write your system in the form
$$
x_1' = 3 x_1 - 2 x_2, \\
x_2' = 2 x_1 - 2 x_2.
$$
And substitute there
$$
x_1 = 2 e^{2t}, \\
x_2 = e^{2t},
$$
with their derivatives
$$
x_1' = 4 e^{2t}, \\
x_2' = 2 e^{2t}.
$$